# Using Cloud Functions as operators in a GC Composer DAG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-composer

Fellow coders,

For a project I'm interested in using [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) to handle several workflows that consist of operations that can be shared between workflows.

It seems to me that Cloud Functions are a perfect way of performing tasks as these operations in a Composer [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=dag).

For what I understood of it, I would need an operator that invokes a cloud function with data that is specific for the task in the specific DAG.

I found a Google Cloud Function operator in the [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/operator/gcp/function.html), however, these are only for deploying and deleting cloud functions, but not for invoking them.

A lot has been written about [invoking DAGs from a cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf), but nothing seems to be written about using cloud functions as operations within a DAG.

**Example use case:**
Every time a document is placed in a certain bucket I want to start a DAG workflow to analyse this document.
This DAG can consist of various tasks, such as extraction of the sender of the document, classification of a logo, or searching for specific words. For these separate tasks, I want to create separate cloud functions that are stitched together in a DAG to compose my workflows.

**Question:**
How to invoke cloud functions from within a Google Composer DAG?
Do people have experience with this or have sample code available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70174703/10375049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) can be used to run Cloud Functions, so you can invoke them from a DAG using the [HTTP operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/http_operator.py). The DAG runs the task, that calls the Cloud Function trigger, than runs the function.