# Google Cloud Composer - having a Cloud Function be a downstream dependent of another Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I have two scripts that I want to run, `function_1` and `function_2`, where `function_2` has to be run only after successful execution of `function_1`.

To do this on GCP I convert each script to a Cloud Function, which I set to be triggered by Pub/Sub as is standard in GCP. Let's say I want to schedule these functions using Composer. Since there's no Operator for executing a Cloud Function, I have to use the Pub/Sub operator to fire a message to my topic, which will in turn execute the function.

Here's my issue: Is it possible to have the trigger for `function_2` in Composer execute only after `function_1` has successfully ran? Since my DAG task is not the execution of the function but rather the firing of the message to Pub/Sub (which in turn runs the function), I don't understand how I can have `function_2` run after the upstream function is fully executed instead of when the Pub/Sub message is sent.

Comment: I have two questions: 1) How much time your function takes to run? 2) In the end of your function, is it possible to publish a message to a PubSub topic saying if the function worked or falied?

Comment: 1) Current function only takes 1-2 minutes so I can make it time based, but that wouldn't work for when the function fails.
2) It's possible to publish a message to PubSub. But is it possible to have Composer only move on to the next step if a specific PubSub message is received?

Comment: Instead of pubsub, you could use Airflow XCOM (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#xcoms) for storing function1 results. Also, For 1-2 minute run, I would consider CloudRun: it is much easier to test than a cloud function, and if you have overlapping runs it might be cheaper than cloud functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Airflow 1.10.1 version Google Cloud Functions Operator got released, this will solve the problem, no need of using the Pub/Sub.

Suppose if you are running  < Airflow 1.10.1, using the http_operator is the workaround, return the status from the GCF.

**Reference:**

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/gcp/function.html

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/http_operator/index.html#module-airflow.operators.http_operator

Comment: I have access to the Google Cloud Functions operator, but that operator only has functionality to delete or deploy a function, not to execute it. So it doesn't solver the problem.

How would you use the http_operator, by firing a message at the end of the function to let Composer know that it's done running?

Comment: At the moment there is not an official way of doing that. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485742/using-cloud-functions-as-operators-in-a-gc-composer-dag) shows basically the same and I agree that at the moment this is the best approach for solving this problem.

Comment: @SANN3 do you have any docs on having Composer wait to run a task until it receives a response code? I wasn't able to find any

Comment: @NeonBlueHair Yes http_operator wait for the response, so trigger a first GCF and inside GCF complete the work and return the response. Then based on the response you can continue on the second step in Airflow. Look for response_check in the above link.